# Connection Refused when trying to create a new user in MongoDB on Kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, permissions

I am using a custom MongoDB image with a read-only file system and trying to deploy it to Kubernetes locally on my Mac using Kind. The below is my statefulset.yaml. I cannot run a custom script called `mongo-init.sh`, which creates my db users. Kubernetes only allows one point of entry, and so I am using that to run my db startup command: `mongod -f /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongod.conf`. It doesn't allow me to run another command or script after that, even if I append a `&` at the end. I tried using `"/bin/bash/", "-c", "command1", "command2"` but that doesn't execute `command2` if my first command is the `mongod` initialization command. Lastly, if I skip the mongod initialization command, the database is not up and running and I cannot connect to it, so I get a connection refused. When I `kubectl exec` onto the container, I can get into the database using mongo shell with `mongo`, but I cannot view anything or really execute any commands because I get an `unauthorized` error. Totally lost on this one and could use some help.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  annotations:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: mydb
  name: mongodb
  namespace: mongodb
spec:
  serviceName: "dbservice"
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mydb
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: mydb
    spec:
      # terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: MONGODB_APPLICATION_USER_PWD
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: MONGODB_APPLICATION_USER_PWD
              name: myconfigmap
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE
              name: myconfigmap
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
              name: myconfigmap
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
              name: myconfigmap
        image: 'localhost:5000/mongo-db:custom'
        command: ["/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.sh"]
        name: mongodb
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data/db
          name: mongodata
        - mountPath: /etc/mongod.conf
          subPath: mongod.conf
          name: mongodb-conf
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.sh
          subPath: mongo-init.sh
          name: mongodb-conf
      initContainers:
        - name: init-mydb
          image: busybox:1.28
          command: ["chown"]
          args: ["-R", "998:998", "/data"]
          volumeMounts:
          - name: mongodata
            mountPath: /data/db
      volumes:
      - name: mongodata
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mongo-volume-claim
      - name: mongodb-conf
        configMap:
          name: myconfigmap
          defaultMode: 0777
```

The error message I see when I do `kubectl logs <podname>`:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://localhost:27017/admin?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server localhost:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to localhost:27017 (127.0.0.1:27017) :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```